# How was the Castle Crashers game for X-box made?

Tags: flash, xbox360, xbox-controller, flash-develop

The graphics and animations for Castle Crashers were [definitely made with Adobe Flash](http://vimeo.com/3062146). But as far as I know X-box doesn't directly support Flash and Adobe Air technology. I love flash for 2D game development and I wonder how to do the trick.
And an additional question: are there easy-to-use libraries for adding gamepad support to Adobe Air app.

Comment: How a specific game was made and "which technology to use" questions are not a good fit for the site. Please read the [FAQ] to learn what types of questions to ask here. Look up skeletal animation for more information about how the animations were made.

Comment: I think this is more of a "which technology was used" not "to use" question.  It's kind of a unique technology approach that was taken (Flash "ported" to X-Box) and personally I'm kind of curious to the answer.

Comment: Just because the graphics were drawn in Flash (ie. what's shown in that video) doesn't mean the game was programmed in Flash. I don't know what technology they used (maybe they did) but just saying.

Comment: It was made with tons of hard work and passion.  Same as any other successful game.  And as always, "how was game X made" is off-topic, since the only people who can correctly answer are the game's creators, not us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks as though the game was designed and made in flash and then the guys at Newgrounds wrote a custom parser and renderer in c++ to run on the xbox (source: http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/1034102). However, to do this in general, it is possible to render the vector graphics from the flash files in a 3D renderer (After parsing and triangulation/etc of course). This is not something that would necessarily be easy for one person to do, but it is not impossible and it should be able to be done with XNA with enough dedication.

Comment: I realize I'm posting this a long time later, but there's a recent interview with the guy that wrote the custom parser for Castle Crashers, and he talks briefly about it, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfOqeeH6Tfg